# Transmit Strings to Main thread from Background thread

Tags: multithreading, javafx, textflow

I need to transmit Strings to Main thread (there is GUI) to add them to javafx' TextFlow.

In the background thread's `run()`, reader waits strings from JSch channel. On new stings it must transmit them to main thread. So main thread can't wait data from background thread (as it is GUI thread), and background thread must send some event with new Strings.

Another trouble, that in application can be, for example, 4 background threads, that reads some data from JSch channel and send it to one window to show.

Answer (score 0):

To transmit data to the GUI thread,use `Platfotm.runLater()` method

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
        /*send your data from here*/
    });
```

`Platform.runLater` makes you modify the GUI thread from other threads, It has a swing equivalent of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Comment: After some reading, I still cannot understand how to use runLater. Here some code for example: http://pastebin.com/Ka1S3Zui . On lines 12 and 24 should be some action.

Comment: @Neka In simple terms,`Platform.runLater` helps you modify the GUI thread from other threads